# How to prevent tab change while giving online test

Tags: javascript

I had Created an Online Test Application. In which I have to give a functionality that is, If some one changes its browser tab or minimize its window,test will get submitted.

I checked on google.Their I saw onchange and onblur event but I am unable to locate code for this.

Will you guys please share your opinion on this and can share code as well.

Thanks 
Mayur Nabeda

Comment: You can check user activity on your page for some time (as per your requirement) and if user is not active then trigger test to submit!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check whether  a browser window is currently active or Not ?
if window is not active You can prompt a warning box that would ask the student to return focus to the window.and terminate the exam if the student still opts switching tab.Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active/1060034#1060034) to check browser window Active